# Access phone number from facebook login Like Uber

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I want to Access phone number from facebook login Like Uber.

I know this question is asked several times and I didn't find any successful answer.
But I'am wondering that Uber is getting phone number and email as well and if user didn't verified phone number before it asks to verify before login completed

here are screens

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, i want to achieve this in my current project, did you find a way?

Comment: Have you got the answer for this ?

Comment: not yet.... you can start bounty or keep voting for it